# How to select Docker host to use with new Eclipse Liberty WDT tools

Tags: eclipse, docker, websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

With last version of Liberty WDT tools for Eclipse, a Liberty server running in a Docker can be configured as server. It works for me and detects the dockers running in a remote host, not locally. I wonder how Liberty has decided to use that specific docker host and how I can configure another one. I mean, the equivalent to the comand:

```
#eval $(docker-machine env MY_HOST)
```

I use in shell to select where my docker commands go to.
I see nowhere in preferences where I can set which set of "docker-machine env" will the tool use.

Thanks

Comment: When you create a server in WDT, in the first step you provide a hostname of the server that is holding Liberty. By default it is localhost, but you can change it to any host. So in your case it will be a host holding docker machine.

Answer (score 0):

The tools don't assume any particular Docker machine but should be listing containers running WebSphere Application Server Liberty on all machines with the machine name in brackets next to the container name.  The tools will handle setting up the environment required for the container that is chosen.  Containers must be started to show in the list.

[image]